# Automation of releases with gitlab CI and bump2version

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, bump2version

I am new on gitlab and I have a python package for which I want to automate the next releases. I would like to have for :

1. A merge on master => creates a new minor version
2. A tag => creates a new major version.

I need a help to do this. does my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is correct ? how a can create this tags ? how I should write my commit messages ? and where I can found the new version references after deployement.

We are working here in github flow, with a features branch and a master branch. (no dev, prod, uat..etc branch)

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: python:latest

stages:
  - test
  - tag
  - deploy

before_script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pytest -vv

tag:
  stage: tag
  script:
    - pip install twine bump2version
    - bump2version release
    - python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
    - TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token python -m twine upload --verbose --skip-existing --repository-url https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi dist/*
  only:
    - tags
      
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - pip install twine bump2version
    - bump2version minor
    - python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
    - TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token python -m twine upload --verbose --skip-existing --repository-url https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi dist/*
  only:
    - master

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - pip install -U sphinx
  - sphinx-build -b html source public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

**setup.py**

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="myApp",  # Replace with your own username
    version="0.0.1",
    author="name NAME",
    author_email="name@email.com",
    description="my new Application",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        "google-auth==1.24.0",
        "pydantic==1.7.3",
        "email-validator==1.1.2",
        "pytest-mock==3.3.1"
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A GitLab job has [predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) which could be of interest when you are calling your script from your `gitlab-ci.yml`.

And since [GitLab 13.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#predefined-cicd-variable-for-commit-author) (April 2021), you now have:

> ### Predefined CI/CD variable for commit author
>
> Previously, if you needed to identify the author of a commit in a running CI/CD job, you had to add an extra API call to the job to retrieve it.
>
> Now, this information is readily available as the `CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR` predefined CI/CD variable.
>
> Thanks to [Craig Andrews](https://gitlab.com/candrews) for this contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/284079).

That can help for your `author`/`author_email` variables, considering that variable is in the `Name <email>` format.